# Left a comment and clicked I am done failed an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

Um... totally strange or maybe a possible bug?

I have got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5695505) in the First Post Review.

All I did was [left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529582/is-it-a-premature-optimization-to-use-stdmove#comment40103512_25530856) and clicked <kbd>I'm done</kbd> but that has failed me...

I'm struggling a bit to understand why?

---

My point is that answers like :

"Why other answers", "Other answers are...", "Why is everyone suggesting..." smells like a forum post not a good SO answer.

If you are answering the question then answer the question and if you want to comment on another answer then you leave a comment - not an answer.

I still was trying to be nice and just leave a comment but .... erg system doesn't like me ;(

---

Also, I would like to ask for a ban lift in this situation as an accumulation of a few incorrect audits (*ones that were "bad" audits not badly reviewed*) has got be banned for 2 days now.

- For example: [Here's one I failed a few days ago...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270166/attention-needed-for-a-specific-question-selected-to-be-an-audit)

Comment: It looks like a comment on the other answers. NAA.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion per ChrisF's answer. The correct action was `"looks good"` and leaving a comment was not a correct action. That's *exotic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the correct response should have been a "Looks Good" or "Skip" - this is based on the score the answer actually has rather than any analysis of its contents.

By adding a comment you are requesting more information or pointing out something that's wrong in the post - both of which are seen as being the wrong thing to do. I don't think the system analyses the contents of the comments so it doesn't matter what you were trying to say, just that you were trying to say *something*.

Comment: Ok I understand that from the system's point of view. Now if a human analysed my comment I wouldn't have failed today's one and the one from a few days ago... Now I am banned which seems just a bit unfair under the given circumstances.

Comment: @mehow - just as a matter of curiosity what was the comment you were adding?

Comment: *"I think this should rather be a comment under an answer or a suggestion to an answerer rather a stand-alone answer."*

Comment: @ChrisF [I think this should rather be a comment under an answer or a suggestion to an answerer rather a stand-alone answer. –  me how 12 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530856/#comment40103512_25530856)

Comment: Ah - I didn't see that the comment actually got added to to the post.

Comment: Ok, should I just come back in 2 days? *(read: never review again*)

Comment: @mehow - the system is giving you an enforced break. Whether you return to reviewing is up to you.

Comment: well, ok... the system did but imo system was wrong. I would like to ask for the ban to be lifted under the circumstances. See the other failed audit (*which shouldn't been failed -> lead to serial downvoting detection*)...

Comment: Wait - are we not supposed to welcome new users? Why let us write a comment if you are going to scold us anyways? Under which circumstances is leaving a comment and not doing anything else a correct action

Comment: @JanDvorak - if the post is good the correct way to welcome a new user is by giving it an up-vote ;)

Comment: _Not_ greeting new users - with a link to a meta post explaining the exacts of the site policies, too big for help/on-topic - is actually an incorrect course of action on some sites. [christianity.se] is one that I know of.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I see no harm in such comments on poor quality posts, but I'd regard such comments **on good quality posts** as noise were I to see them. What's the point in adding them? The user clearly knows what's what.

Comment: The audit should never require a particular voting pattern. Some questions are just not worth any votes, but it got enough attention and thus votes to become an audit anyways.

Comment: @JanDvorak - the choice of posts for audit is a separate problem.

Comment: but clicking "it's good!" is against the rules [*of another SO system*] as well because the answer in fact is not a good answer - it should be a comment.

Comment: @mehow - That's the root cause of the problem. The system chose the answer as a "looks good" based purely on the score NOT the content.

Comment: @chris how do you rate christianity's policy to greet everyone? Are you going to stop them because good contributors (and everyone's considered good until proven otherwise) don't need help? Let them, then slap them in the face once audits are enabled there? I simply disagree that there's no such thing as a useful comment to a decent question.

Comment: @JanDvorak - If I were a completely new user (i.e. this was my first SE site) then I'd probably be OK with it. However, if I joined as an experienced SE user I'd be insulted to get such a comment on my first post. However, on a site like SO this would get out of hand so quickly it's better not to do it.

Comment: @ChrisF no ban lift for me then??

Comment: @mehow - Ban lifted - but take a bit more time over your reviews.