# Why are Review Audits not more clear and well-explained?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I was wondering why we even have review audits, if they're implemented such that many of them are ambiguous? Why aren't they carefully chosen to be clear?

In my opinion audits should be hand-picked, not random machine-picked (AFAIK that's the case right now), and the people who hand-pick them should also explain the exact reason why you failed. Then it would also make sense to ban people from reviews for 2 days. Right now, the explanation is just as helpful as "You were wrong. Period."

Why not spend a little time on improving the whole thing?

Comment: Because the majority of audit reviews are *not* ambiguous.

Comment: Majority? Seriously? What about the other ones? The minority? Why do people have to settle on the *almost* perfect thing?

Comment: Nothing is perfect. Including the people that would be hand-picking the review audits.

Comment: Avoid the complaint biasing effect, a 0.01% failure rate produces 100% of the noise.  I have yet to see a Thank You note from a user that failed an audit.  Any system that's expected to be 99.999% perfect is never completed.

Comment: True, but if people hand-picked the audits, they would also be able to enter an explanation, why the question/answer had to be accepted/rejected. It should be all about the teaching (how to review), not about punishment.

Comment: @HansPassant why would I thank a faulty system? A simple explanation on why we should have taken a different decision would be enough.

Comment: @EduardLuca: you'd still see it as punishment if you failed the review. It *is* about learning; those that want to learn and misunderstood something do come to Meta, for example.

Comment: @EduardLuca: hand-picking audits won't scale; we'd not get enough audits to *keep auditing*, which is what the system does now. The other goal is to make sure you are paying attention, and didn't just drift of clicking your way through.

Comment: cross-site dupe: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/165773) at MSE. @MartijnPieters I pass about 99,99% of audits but per my observations, saying that majority of them is unambiguous is somewhat too optimistic

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why not? They could be given to people with extremely high reps. Role models if you wish. This way it's handled by the community, and no attention from SO would be necessary. Just like reviews work now.

Comment: @gnat thanks for that, didn't look over there. Weird how that post has +83 votes and this one has -2, and they're both saying the same thing using other words.

Comment: @EduardLuca see [Is it possible on MSE to question something that people hold dear without getting “disagreement downvoted”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209244/165773) -- "...an alternative is to write the question in a way that would literally force audience to read it through despite the negative score (a prominent example is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/171172/timeline "note 18 (eighteen) downvotes, closure and reopen in the timeline dated Mar 10 '13")). Many askers seem to believe they're capable of that, but per my observations at MSO, this skill is _extremely_ rare..."

Comment: @EduardLuca it could be a lot of reasons (including time - that post is over 18 months old), but your question is hardly saying the same thing in other words.  The user there presented a number of examples of poor audit questions, and a complete plan on how to implement it.  You just said "audits should be hand picked" and a custom message on why should be added.  I'm not saying your feature request is a bad idea (I don't think it is feasible on the scale we deal with), but it is really just a vague idea without much else.

Comment: Some of the audits I get are so bad, I thought they *were* hand-written. That said, I've got fewer failures over time, so I must have learnt something.

Comment: Shameless [link to my feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190875/227881) to provide more informations on the review bans. It ain't bad to fail, it is to fail a lot.

Comment: I don't think the audits need to be hand-picked, but I *do* think the review audit system could use a lot of work.  Right now it's frustrating to use. There are already various feature requests and discussions out there about the finer points of what needs fixing.

Comment: @eddie_cat yeah, the hand-picked thing was just an idea, there are probably better ones.

Comment: I also think some are ambiguous ... like a link-only answer containing a bit of explanation ... I was banned for a month for this (http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9864182) ... even the answer was inside StackOverflow so I can assume it will stay. Nobody wants to copy/retype a complete text. 

The answer above was not the best, but according to me also not 'audit-proof' wrong. Guess I was wrong. Next month another chance I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why?

Because they help reviewers understand the review process.

---

A few months ago when I was a new user and earned the privilege to review, I eagerly started reviewing the first two queues at 500 reputation.

I wanted to help!

But I didn't understand how one should judge the quality of first posts and late answers. More importantly, I failed to understand the importance of the "skip" button.

I didn't upvote the high quality posts in audits and was banned for 48 hours.

### Result

The ban made me aware that I was doing *something* wrong. I started participating in Meta to learn the rules, and am [an active participant till date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation). I became a better reviewer and after doing tons of reviews between that day and today, in all six review queues, I never failed an audit or got banned.

And most importantly, I learnt to distinguish between a good post and a bad post.

*I don't remember what those audits were, or whether they were good audits or bad audits.* Even if someone would have handpicked them, it wouldn't have mattered. The ban introduced me to Meta, and helped me improve myself. That's all that matters at the end of the day.

From my own experience, I learnt that audits *are* useful.

Comment: It's important to realize that the purpose of audits are not to teach people how to review.  They're there to kick out the absolutely worst of the worst, the people that aren't paying the slightest bit of attention, basically, the bots.  It's more or less just a captcha.  Being able to pass the audits doesn't mean you're not a good reviewer, it means you're actually reading the posts in question.  Or at least, that's how they were designed.

Comment: Some users innocently do bad reviews. It serves quite a bit of educational purpose when one is at 500 rep, and hesitates to cast downvotes on answers due to rep loss, or even edit posts. 500 rep is too low, you hardly know the software at that time, and the audits are a wake up call @Servy. After the ban, the "skip" button suddenly became visible to me, earlier I hardly noticed that it exists.

Comment: I agree that the rep limits for several of the review queues are way too low, and that this contributes to the number of very poor reviewers.  My point is simply that if audits are the only tool you have to figure out how to review, you won't be a good reviewer.  That's simply not what they're there to do.  Learning enough about reviewing to pass audits still leaves you as a pretty poor reviewer, if that's your only source of knowledge on how to review.

Comment: @Servy I don't agree (and that's the whole point of my post). There are lots of edge cases on audits (I got 2 so far and screwed up both of them -- with one, I still believe I did the correct thing). I'm just saying: tell people what they did wrong, so they don't do it again. And **Infinite Recursion**, yes, participating on Meta would somewhat solve this, but the learning curve is too slow IMO.

Comment: I agree @Servy. Meta participation is important to understand what is good and what is bad. Audits are not useful as the only source of knowledge. It just pushes the user from SO proper to Meta. Get banned, visit Meta and learn how to review.

Comment: Also, @InfiniteRecursion you say `Because they help reviewers understand the review process`. That's wrong, and you said it yourself in your comment. Audits help people understand **that** they made a mistake, but not **why**.

Comment: @EduardLuca Every once in a while there is a bad review, sure.  Of the one audit you've gotten that you feel you did the right thing on, getting it wrong wouldn't result in you being banned.  You must have gotten several other audits wrong to actually get banned.

Comment: Nope, just got two. One was an honest mistake.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion But it doesn't actually do that for the vast majority of users.  Your example is an exception.

Comment: @Eduard: The learning curve is slow, but it's worth the effort because effort is expected from reviewers. Janitor work is hard on SO, burns you out. Yet lots of users are actively cleaning up and keeping the site clean. Reviewing is not mandatory. But for those who do it, they are expected to invest the effort.

Comment: @Servy: My answer is too localized then. Let's wait till someone comes along and writes a wiki answer or a rant answer.

Comment: @Servy _"not to teach people how to review"_ -- really? have you read [audits tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info) and the [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/165773) referred from these? **"designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills..."**

Comment: @gnat SE has specifically said on many occasions that the review system was designed to make sure that people are paying attention, and that it's not designed to ensure that the reviewer is actually a quality reviewer.  It's been listed as an explicitly design goal that someone who has taken the time to read the post should be able to pass an audit.  That's all it's designed to measure.  Does it sometimes do more, sure, but that's not what it's designed to do, and when requests have been made to make audits more rigorous in the past have been declined for that reason.

Comment: @Servy if honestly, I don't give a $%^& about how many "occasions" were there. Thing is, when there is an [official faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info "moderator-only tag"), people don't search and count "occasions" saying one way or another; instead they proceed straight to [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/165773) to learn how things are intended to work. If those whose "occasional" remarks you've read were honest / serious, they would put an effort into adjusting the faq... but they didn't

Comment: @gnat So do you think that audits actually do a good job of actually teaching people how to review?  Do you think that someone who is capable of passing all of the audits they see is going to be a good reviewer?  If it is actually a primary goal of the system, contrary to repeated statements to the contrary, then it's certainly not a *successful* goal of the system.  It *doesn't* do that, even if it should.  I don't give a damn what the FAQ says on the subject, they don't actually *accomplish* what it says they do.  If someone thinks that they do, they're mistaken.

Comment: @Servy I am merely addressing the statement about their purpose made in [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271095/why-are-review-audits-not-more-clear-and-well-explained/271104?noredirect=1#comment92837_271104): "purpose of audits are not to teach people how to review", pointing out that [official faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/165773) currently says rather opposite: "designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills..."

Comment: @gnat And yet SE has stated, repeatedly, that that's not their intention, they don't accomplish that goal, and SE has stated that they have no intention of actually changing the audits so that they will accomplish that goal.  Clearly the FAQ is wrong.  It is not infallible.  Every single other point of evidence, to which there is a lot of it, points to it being wrong.

Comment: @Servy whatever you state about FAQ here, it's merely a 20th or 30th comment buried deep down below in heavily downvoted obscure discussion at a per site meta. No matter how loud you challenge it here, in the comments, the matter of fact is, people ain't going to search every single meta out there only to find that you declared faq wrong. They will go to the faq and learn from there - unless of course there is a comparably visible challenge of some statement in it... but there isn't

Comment: @gnat Okay.  What's your point?  My point is that this answer is incorrect and that audits aren't actually helping most reviewers become better reviewers.  You point simply seems to be that some new users are going to expect audits to make them better reviewers despite the fact that they won't.  That's certainly true.  Some people will mistakenly believe that audits are teaching people how to review properly.  That's a problem, and we should fix it.

Comment: @Servy my point is, your explanation of why answer is incorrect doesn't look compelling. Actually, given that you didn't refer faq (even in form like "despite [faq stating otherwise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/165773)"), some may argue that it looks ignorant

Comment: @Servy: Incorrect? [Others don't think so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271118/2982225). Review audits make some users rant (the ones that refuse to learn), but that is not the entire picture. There are lots of new users who learn from review bans, just because they don't rant on Meta, it doesn't mean audits don't teach.

Comment: @gnat Really?  I thought your point was that nobody is going to read it anyway?  Well, now that you've mentioned the FAQ, and we agree that it's wrong (?), you've now succeeded in enhancing my assertion by acknowledging the misleading FAQ entry.  Thanks.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I find that answer conflicting.  It says that he agrees with this answer, yet at the same time it states, "They are meant to be good enough to get people to pay attention."  That's pretty well supporting my point, that the audits don't really teach, they just assert people are paying attention.  I'd also like to take a second to point out that someone like you who is willing to take the time to go to meta, read around, learn how to review properly, etc. is someone who, most likely, would have done all of those things even in a world without audits. Most people don't do that.

Comment: I agree, I am indeed that kind of a person. I can now understand your point of view @Servy.

Comment: So I guess to sum up, people should come to Meta each time something's not clear. Still thing it's an overhead, but hey, who am I to argue.

Answer (score 8):

[Infinite Recursion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2982225/infinite-recursion) has an excellent answer, so I won't address those points.

The review audits are not meant to be perfect. They are meant to be *good enough* to get people to pay attention. Most of them are incredibly obvious, in my experience. Some require a moment to think about (which is the point, to begin with). Then there are a small percentage which you could argue are wrong, and occasionally, one that is flat out, obviously wrong.

I've failed a couple of the latter, and a handful of the penultimate. But the vast majority of audits I have very easily passed. (Disclosure: The review system and audits did not come out until not long before I was elected as a moderator, so one would hope I would do very well on them.)

If you are regularly failing audits, though; I think the answer Infinite Recursion left gives some really good information.

Comment: That's the thing. This was my first time failing, but I figured that if I fail, I should at least know why, so that I won't fail next time. Does that not make sense?

Comment: @EduardLuca The concept does make sense, yes. But the effort required to provide that information would be massive, and would be prone to errors with potentially very negative effect; Someone enters a reason for an audit that doesn't match (or contradicts) other audit reasons - or general Review standards. The user becomes much more confused because to them, the audit reason will seem Authoritative™. Due to the weight of the effect that these would have, it's better not to provide that instruction, but to let people ask the community about specific instances.

Comment: I don't think you should be discouraged from meta participation  because your first post here wasn't well received @EduardLuca, you well-elaborated your thoughts, the votes were to express opinions and that they do not agree with "Why are Review Audits not more clear and well-explained?". As I mentioned Meta is a great place to gather accurate feedback from the community __instead of the person who has to write it__, who will eventually burn out from writing a "fail summary" for every audit task in the system..

Answer (score 5):

> Why not spend a little time on improving the whole thing?

You're a developer / programmer too. We all know how hard it is to have the best system.

I would like to break down the main blockers for improving "the whole thing" (the review system) into... some smaller things:

#### Planning (Research and development)!

Every good system must be well-thought and carefully planned. This includes having a flow for the users (reviewers) to work with the system and be able to navigate it without problems. This includes:

- A viable design that allows users to surf with minimal documentation! A good service should be self-documenting and its instructions should be as critical as its interface.
- A design that is not problematic to implement. This includes technical limitations, such as server resources and the stress to limit for both server and client side...
- Whether it will be welcomed by the community,
- *et cetera.*

Note that the current system binds the "audit decision" to posts that are deemed "high quality" or "low quality" based on its algorithm. `<assumption>` How it was received by the reviewers - a flat side response may indicate the correct feedback to take for this task, for example all reviewers in a LQP task decides to "Recommend close" , how it was received by the community - +8 upvotes with no downvotes on an answer may indicate it being high-quality? `</assumption>`

While there will be disputes on specific cases based on the specific scenarios with this system, such as **link-only answers** with little value without the link getting upvoted for its temporal usefulness *just then*, or answers that should be posted as a comment which were mercifully "Looks OK"-ed by the reviewers and caused the system to think it was not a problematic post... This does not deem the design terrible:

- Disputed audits were brought to community / moderator attention with the tag [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits). They can get fixed, or the developers / moderators try to explain what was correct / not about the audits.
- While failing audits are punishing, it does make up for the incurred education within our reviewers. [See Infinite Recursion's answer for a great, detailed example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271104/3622940). Honestly, ***reviewing is hard*** and audits are there to stop (and **correct) us** before we make enough mistakes to disrupt the community participation. I sometimes come to a task and think "Oh boy, I'm not sure what to do." Were there without audits I would probably click a random button, since there would be no consequences for being in a "community-managed site". Thankfully there are audits so I would pay *extra attention* to the post if I bother (research about it, look at the main post and revision histories) or skip to let another reviewer <s>screw up</s> do the work.
- Audits are effective. Currently we have "robo reviewers" over the place approving / rejecting / leave opening / (insert robo responses here) everything (and failing even the most obvious suggested edit audits which are simply automated vandalism). By having audits and rating a pass / fail for specific random tasks, reviewers who do not review carefully / review poorly will be punished accordingly. While bans may or may not be too harsh, that is another topic, and truly does stop reviewers, and even enlightens some to go through their review history to realize their mistakes and improve...

#### Implementation!

- I was wondering why we even have review audits, if they're implemented such that many of them are ambiguous?

[Audits are tests for reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/), and it would make sense only to blend into the regular reviewing process. Having a "You've done good job reviewing. Take a task with a 'This is a test to see if you're paying attention!' banner" procedure is not a constructive measure here.

- Why aren't they carefully chosen to be clear?

No system is perfect. There are disputed cases but that does not render the chosen audit tasks as uncarefully chosen, frankly mistakes, just like what we all make. :)

- Audits should be hand-picked, not random machine-picked?

It's not a very viable idea, considering hand-picked audits are not perfect either. While they *might* be *slightly better*, the additional effect will not make up for taking the person's time hand-picking the posts as audits.
(Plus, let's all just admit that good posts are hard to find around now.)

- The people who hand-pick them should also explain the exact reason why you failed. *[...]* Right now, the explanation is just as helpful as "You were wrong. Period."

A common way to learn from the mistakes would be to post the audit and your response in the audit in a chat room or post a meta thread, and **be open to feedback** as well. To have a detailed feedback queued in case a reviewer fails is to display, is not necessarily beneficial in terms of the implementation. *Moreover, you cannot guarantee* that the reviewers would read text after "You were wrong" if they do add it. *It's better this way.* YMMV.

#### Evaluation!

Users review. By taking audits, they learn they are doing the right thing or not. While some reviewers cheat by opening the parent post of the task in a new window to view its state and handle accordingly, most users are able to learn "I should upvote great content" and "I should deal with bad content, not 'no action needed' / 'looks ok'".

The audit feedback currently given as an automatic comment works fine. Actions such as deleting and closing are for posts with serious problems, and posts that has been handled with these measures are considered to have serious problems; Upvoting is to indicate questions showing research effort, is useful or is clear (seen in its tooltip), and posts which receives sufficient upvotes to be decided as a high quality post by the system will **really** be a high-quality post, and reviewers should upvote accordingly. ***These messages are clear and useful for reviewers.** Some just don't pay attention and read them.*

<sup>acronym: PIE. yes remember it, it is good. Trust me, I'm the Unihedron. `:D`</sup>

In conclusion, audits are not really as "not more clear and well-explained", but instead the opposite. They are essential to the current system and keeps reviewers doing the good. It's not as beneficial to "make them more well-explained" or "make them more clear", and these three points as I demonstrated above.

---

Postscript: Congratulations on your [Reviewer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer?userid=898423) for reviewing 250 Low Quality Posts :)

Postscript two: I'm not ready for reviewing either. I find myself more productive outside the queues than following through them during [the ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270848/3622940), and recently started playing around with SEDE queries to catch up bad content instead. ;)

Comment: Excellent answer. I hope the OP accepts this answer, because it is more comprehensive and addresses all the issues.