# Why are my badges in MSO different from SO but the reputation remains the same?

Tags: support, badges, meta

On Stack Overflow I have ten badges and in Meta Stack Overflow I have only three, as shown below:

1) Stack Overflow

[image: Stack Overflow badges]

2) Meta Stack Overflow

[image: Meta Stack Overflow badges]

Why this difference, or will take time to reflect in MSO?

From yesterday it is showing the same.

Comment: Badges are per-site, meta's don't have reputation, that is copied from the main site.

Comment: Why is this down voted now? Question may be simple but i dont know. If there is already a question similar to this, i guess people have privilage to make it duplicate. But I dont understand why i got these many downvotes. is it not clear? is something wrong?Please someone explain,so that i can correct myself.

Comment: Lack of research could be one. Furthermore voting on meta doesn't do anything for your rep so I won't be bothered to much about it. You are not even close to my [most down voted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270848/reject-and-edit-response-should-not-fail-an-audit/270852#270852). Remember that meta is [different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) and so is its voting... a little bit more harsh than it is on main.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I got the solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) .

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

And Sorry for not seeing this before.