# Why did I fail an audit for flagging as off-topic when the question asks about features missing from a PHP installation?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I received the following question as an audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6056879?filter-tags=android

Since it's a question about why a particular PHP feature wasn't installed, I flagged it as a professional server administration question.

Is this question appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: It *could* be a server admin question, but its also "a question about a tool commonly used by programmers". Possibly on-topic on both sites, probably not the greatest audit ever.

Comment: My reading of [help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:" would indicate that professional administrative items are off-topic even when they might overlap with "a question about a tool commonly used by programmers",

Comment: Yes, except the last line with the professional administrative items says: "unless they directly involve programming or programming tools" Which a PHP server probably is (could a PHP expert chime in here?). Like I said, its potentially borderline, but not an obvious "off-topic" question for me.

Comment: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: This may not be a great audit question, but it is evidence that you don't understand the closing criteria.  Be vary cautious about moving configuration questions *off* the site populated by people who deal with the tools in question every day, to a site where there is likely no *specific* knowledge about them.

Comment: And for that reason alone, its actually served its purpose, as we are discussing this and everybody is learning something (hopefully).

Comment: I see it as border-line as well, but it's actually more towards the *off-topic* border. While it does meet the criteria that it be related to a tool used by programmers, it assumes too much of a relationship. Just because you know how to write some PHP doesn't mean you know anything about how PHP is installed on a server. In particular, the question is actually related to an update to Mac OS X which installed a new build of PHP, one which neglected a compiler flag of all things. Your standard PHP dev isn't going to know what to do with that.

Comment: Yes, this question is on-topic for Stack Overflow.  I agree with the other comments stating that it's border line.  Err on the side of keeping it.  Over-moderation is a bad thing.

Comment: "professional administrative" I don't get that sense at all. This sounds like a dev managing his local box. (How many servers do you know of running Mac OS X?) I would never call IT for a problem with my language runtime on my local box, unless they forced out an update or something.

Comment: @jpmc26: It's actually more common than you think. Apple still produces a server version of OS X, and especially since the Mac Mini was introduced there's people using them as racks, essentially.

Comment: Related: [MSE: Do questions on WAMP belong on Stack Overflow, Server Fault or Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208052/167646)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have failed the audit because the audit system chose a highly upvoted question assuming since it has got so many upvotes it must be good...The truth is it wasn't a good, on-topic question but it's good that the audit system brought this question to our attention because now the question gets its deserved justice - downvotes and closure.

The reason you have failed is rather obvious - the audit system couldn't know the question was off-topic because it had a lot of upvotes...

Don't worry much about it. If it didn't get you banned from reviewing then there is nothing to worry about - if you did - I'm sure a moderator can lift the ban up.

Tip for the future -> If you are convinced that a question is off-topic but it shows up in the review queue - open the question in a new tab. If at this point you realize it is an audit - you can always skip it (*because you know that *looks good* is not the correct action) and bring the question up on meta or [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) to get some attention.

Comment: Have moderators ever lifted a temp review ban from failing a bad audit question before?  The response I've always seen has been a variant of:  "One fail won't matter if you're doing well, and if you were 1 fail away when you got hit by the bad question you probably deserved the wristslap away.  Next time be more careful."

Comment: @DanNeely from own experience: ...[**yes**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270624/left-a-comment-and-clicked-i-am-done-failed-an-audit#comment89886_270625). I have failed 2 or 3 audits within a short time frame and reported them all to meta. After the last one I have gotten a ban and asked the moderator to lift it and yes it has been lifted.

Comment: Ok.  Never happened to me; including when I got myself banned over broken audits (question deleted while in the queue type stuff) and went button mashing to get as much bug report detail only to discover the only thing that didn't generate an error was the fail route...

Comment: "If you are convinced that a question is off-topic but it shows up in the review queue - open the question in a new tab. If at this point you realize it is an audit"-- What should one look for to realize it is an audit? Simply if it's upvoted a lot, or what?

Comment: It was an on-topic question.  It's unfortunate you disagree with the community which chose to upvote it in the first place.  Your suggestion of bypassing a review audit implies that you've done this a few times before... that's disappointing.

Comment: I don't understand how the question is off topic. The impression I get from the question as hand is that it's a developer managing their local machine and the PHP runtime on it. That makes it a perfect fit for, "tools commonly used by programmers." Could you elaborate or why you consider it off topic?

Comment: Involve a moderator please.... I and other at least 14 people thought the question was off-topic.

Comment: I do wonder sometimes, if SO's core service to its users is getting questions answered, or getting questions correctly classified into neat little pigeon holes.

Comment: @vba4all Moderators are not the "supreme overlords" deciding what is and isn't on-topic, that's a job for us, the *community*.

Comment: @hichris123 there is a reason they are called Community Moderators - they're the people you turn to when a community fails to collaborate. They have been chosen by us....I think involving a moderator in this particular case wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Victor this may be related to the brainless audit system attempting to present gray area / borderline question as a perfectly good fit for the site. If the same question was brought in in the context of, say, routine [meta-tag:migration], discussion would probably be (much) more lighthearted

Answer (score 8):

While the question is *formulated* from an server-operation perspective, it's not limited to server administration. In fact, being a PHP developer I noticed quite a few processes failing because the support for PNGs had disappeared without notice. Currently, I'm finding ways to deal with the problem in a workable fashion. None of this involves *running a server* with PHP enabled, and directly *impacts the actual development* of software.

So from that point of view, it's on-topic.

Needless to say, this particular subject has been a dominant issue this past week at my software house.

It's even more surprising if you read the reason as

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Since /usr/bin/php is the last tool a PHP developer can do without, compared to specific editors, the reason as written actually blatantly contradicts to taken action.

The end result here is that there's a group of people that upvote here, myself included, because they ran into an acute problem and posted a question stating "an upgrade broke my development tools, how to fix", and a group of people that are don't see the problem first-hand, see a reference to "web server", and subsequently insist it has to be closed off-topic (or perhaps, moved to superuser). In other words, there are two camps to this problem, both having legitimate reasons.

Having two camps eventually turned into the case where the end result is that the people who have no message to the actual problem consider it proper cause to deny the answer to those who need it and consider this the best place to ask, or a question with both a high number of close votes and upvotes. Subsequently **the audit did what it was meant to do and decided "preserve" was the correct answer because it was apparent a significant part of the audience of this website apparently depend on it**. That may be problematic because you voted on the "wrong" camp in a polarizing case like this, but it can happen.

Comment: that *the audit did what it was meant to do and preserved a question because it's apparent a significant part of the audience of this website apparently depend on it.* is a complete misunderstanding of the purpose of audits.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bad audit — the question certainly seems off-topic to me. I have downvoted it and voted to close it; *hopefully* that should get it out of the audit queue.

I feel this question is off-topic because it *does not directly involve any software under development*. While it's possible that the user is using PHP on Mac OS X as part of a development environment, the question is not at all specific to that use case; it could just as easily be a question about using a Mac OS X system as a web server in production. (Simply because a tool *can* be used for software development doesn't make all questions about it on-topic. For instance, questions about using a text editor are usually off-topic, even if you're using that text editor to write code.) Moreover, the solution to this problem will involve system administration tasks (e.g, installing another version of PHP, or recompiling it), not software development tasks.

(That being said, you probably should have spotted this as an audit because it wasn't tagged as "android". I don't feel that takes anything away from this question's being off topic, though.)

Comment: How can an audit be off-topic?

Comment: @vba4all Bad wording: the audit is bad; the question is off-topic.

Comment: Re. "questions about using a text editor are usually off-topic, even if you're using that text editor to write code." This is not true for `vi` or `emacs`, for example. There are currently [25,829 open questions tagged vi, vim, or emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+[vim]+or+[vi]+or+[emacs]+) and the general consensus is that questions about these editors are not automatically off-topic. See, for example, [Can we please have a ruling about Emacs questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79659) on Meta SE.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Huh. I may have chosen a bad example; [vi vs. emacs questions is a really nasty situation](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/18170/closing-the-vi-vim-proposal). (TL;DR: There is an emacs SE, but the proposal for a vi/vim SE was rejected a few weeks ago.) I personally disagree with this decision; vi(m) is not fundamentally a programming tool.