# Close Vote Review Queue audit on active bounty question

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits

Going through the close vote review queue I got [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9478352) for [Simplify process with linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396897/simplify-process-with-linq-query) which has an active bounty.

According to [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560)

> FYI, bountied questions are already excluded from use as audits in the Close, Reopen and Triage queues. Should probably just do that everywhere.

The question also had the banner on it for the bounty before I even did my review action:

[image]

Is this just a bug or did something change?

Comment: Maybe it got select as an audit and after that the bounty was added?

Comment: Are audits pre-selected?  I would have thought something like having an active bounty would have been checked when it pulled it from the pool of audit questions.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is no active query-ing of the posts table if it isn't for showing questions on the front-page....

Comment: I had the impression that questions used for audits were indeed pre-selected. However, if one of the specifications for audits is "no question with a bounty shall be shown as an audit" then you *have* to check whether it has a bounty *again* just before you show it to someone as an audit (and perhaps recheck its entire eligibility). It seems to me if this is not done, then there's a significant risk that a question that was pre-selected for an audit could have acquired a bounty in the meantime.

Comment: [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10190771?filter-closereason=toobroad)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build; just some minor confusion over two similar names ("closed" vs "closes")

Comment: Was this a general fix for all review queues or just the close one? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308685/792066

Comment: @Braiam close and triage