# Triage test questions shouldn't display bounties or comments

Tags: bug, triage

I've been going through the triage queue and I've encountered this

[image]

From that it is pretty obvious that it is a "Looks OK" test question, because no new question can have a bounty on it, and bad questions usually don't attract bounties (and the user has high rep). Thus it seems strange to include this information.

Something similar also applies for the votes and comments — why is the information included there? An argument could be made that the person asking was clarifying the question, however that should be done in the question anyways, and from my (although limited) experience more often then not I see just comments saying that they flagged it or something similar, which obviously affects my decision.

What is the reasoning behind including all this information? Isn't it counter-productive?

Comment: Audits aren't meant to be hard. This is a great audit for someone that's blindly rejecting everything.

Comment: This should be a bug as *FYI, bountied questions are already excluded from use as audits in the Close, Reopen and Triage queues. Should probably just do that everywhere. – Shog9♦ Jul 31 at 17:31* ([source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560)).  also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305872/close-vote-review-queue-audit-on-active-bounty-question

Comment: *bad questions usually don't attract bounties* - They did briefly a few weeks ago because bounties also tend to attract up votes, thus keeping the question open. There were a few Meta posts where people were failing audits due to obviously off topic questions having bounties on them.

Comment: There was also at least one feature request for making bounties exempt from audits. I guess making the bounty visible in Triage was the solution to that problem.

Comment: @BSMP What do you mean "briefly"?  It's not particularly uncommon at all for a bad question to get a bounty.

Comment: We shouldn't be showing these _as audits_ anywhere. You _should_ occasionally see a question with a bounty come through triage, as there are cases of kinda stinky questions with bounties that could conceivably be improved in the helper queue, but they shouldn't  be audits. Re-tagging this as a bug.

Comment: @Servy - There seemed to be a lot of Meta posts about them back in August but then seemed to stop. I guess if I spent more time (than not at all) on the bounties page I'd have realized it wasn't a fluke or weird blip.

Comment: So given that questions with bounties legitimately show up in the triage queue sometimes, if you removed them from the audits wouldn't you just make the opposite problem?  I.e. if you saw a question with a bounty, you would know it belonged in the queue and you could reject it without worrying about it being an audit?