# Failed FP audit due to downvote. Is my mental rule for downvoting wrong?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, downvotes, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit in First Posts which now locks me out for 2 days. While I perfectly understood why I failed before (misclicked button, misinterpreted problem statement), I was puzzled by that one.

In particular, it was this question: [Create a prolog program that solves the peg jump puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879616/create-a-prolog-program-that-solves-the-peg-jump-puzzle)

I downvoted and was about to comment that the author should please include some information about what "doesn't work" mean. They *did* include the desired output, that's something at least (but could be copied from the problem statement they had), but there was no information what failed (error message? incorrect result - if yes, which?) and what the OP already tried to do about the problem. (And I'm not the only one who thought that, according to the second comment.)

It appeared to me like a problem statement copied from an assignment plus the incorrect code.

This failed the audit because it was a "high quality question".

Now this made me think, am I downvoting too quickly? I read a few threads about this here at meta SO but the opinions vary between "downvote without comment at the slightest problem" to "hardly ever downvote at all" and it often appears to derail into protecting newcomers or not etc. etc.

If the question is written in a way that essential information, or information which would make understanding the problem a lot easier (such as what "doesn't work" mean, something I see all the time), is missing, I downvote and comment about it. Is this wrong? Should I only comment in this case? What defines that it is wrong and causes an audit to fail?

I read that the audit system is automatic, but things like this are confusing - in case I was right and the audit was wrong, is there any way to vote for an audit being bad...? Again, assuming I was right (correct me otherwise), aren't others also going to fall for a bad audit, causing frustration?

**EDIT:** Since the system asked me to explain how this question is different from [that one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795): I am specifically asking about downvoting (not OT flags), plus about whether there are ways to flag bad audits. My question is a bit more complex than the other one, it would appear.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I probably would have downvoted / commented, I'm not one to dredge through prolog code to see what "doesn't work." Even if they just added an actual outcome alongside their expected, it would be more helpful than what's pasted.

Comment: It only got extra attention and all those upvotes because of the [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36879616/timeline#vote_113337900).  It's an ok question, but not really worth 12 upvotes IMO.  I can see why you'd want to downvote it.

Comment: I agree. A downvote is justified here. This is one of those cases where the system picked a bad post to use for an audit.

Comment: Hm I missed the bounty. Then maybe the system should not consider questions with bounties in the first place? Because I noticed something similar on a question I put a bounty on myself: It was sitting around for a long time and even earned me a tumbleweed badge, and when I put a bounty on it (shortly before I found my - rather trivial - mistake anyway), it suddenly started getting upvotes quickly.

Comment: @CherryDT Here's a relevant feature request: [Exclude open-bounty questions in review audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278398/exclude-open-bounty-questions-in-review-audits)

Comment: I see; I'll comment there that I think it should also exclude questions which once had a bounty (regardless of whether it's still open or not).

Comment: [Good information here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560): `FYI, bountied questions are already excluded from use as audits in the Close, Reopen and Triage queues. Should probably just do that everywhere.- Shog9♦ `. Here's the discussion where I found the quote:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305872/close-vote-review-queue-audit-on-active-bounty-question

Comment: @CherryDT Aside, I'm pretty sure commenting on a First Post audit that is "good" also fails the audit.

Comment: Oh. Didn't even realize that. Thanks for pointing that out! - Although I'm not sure why, actually, because there I might want to give the OP a hint about something which isn't worth a full answer, or ask for some details based on a gut feeling even though the question is high quality on its own already...

Comment: @CherryDT Here is another relevant discussion :) [Is it consensus that commenting should (not) lead to failing review audits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306916/is-it-consensus-that-commenting-should-not-lead-to-failing-review-audits) And an actual `feature-request` post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment

Comment: Oh okay... I'm still not getting used to that for everything I want to comment here, a feature request already exists somewhere ;)

Comment: I know the feeling!

Comment: Low-milage tags (in this case, [tag:prolog]), are full of folks who are so desperate to have questions to answer that they upvote whatever foul dreck slops in front of them.  It's not surprising a help vampire question would end up with lots of upvotes and get you a two day vaycay from reviewing.

Comment: Well to be fair, it just happened to be the one which got me the two day vaycay, but only because I failed before. It could have been the other way round as well of course, so this question here is not supposed to be a rant about the 2d "penalty".

Comment: WTF? Why is there even any punishment for downvoting, regardless of how brilliant question is, what bounty it have or whatever else?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov upvote the feature request linked by cubejockey. Its the only thing we can do at this point. But a minor retort: multiple audit failures triggered a punishment, this single audit failure would have only triggered a harsh slap on the wrist.

Comment: @Gimby, I'd rather remove any punishment for downvoting whatever question than just remove bounties from review.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: So, remove that aspect of review audits entirely? Or what?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov But the problem is not only in downvoting, the problem is that such a question is mistaken to be a great high-quality question, and any action you would take because you deem it low-quality would make you fail the audit.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, yes, exactly. Any user may have dozens valid reasons for downvoting something even if it is universally liked by everyone else. Telling them "you MUIST vote as majority or get punished" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Will your comment about us Prolog folk desperate for any foul dreck has no merit to it whatsoever: only 2 upvotes before bounty; first Prolog answer only after a week; there being absolutely NO way for you to know who was actually voting - most likely some random students (because unusually high views number); etc.. We the desperate Prolog folks like to engage with newcomers instead of haughtily slamming them as help vampires -- never mind the significant chunk of nearly-functional code and the expected output posted in the question!.. how uncool of us.

Comment: The prolog tag is basically one big voting ring. This has been noticed before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319598/prolog-absurdistan-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @AndrewMedico um, no. all you have is one guy's heavily downvoted exaggerated suspicions, disputed and detracted in a highly upvoted answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a questionable audit.  The question itself isn't terrible, but it's not the kind of question you'd expect to see for having a score of 12.  I think that a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36879616/timeline#vote_113337900) put on the post got it extra attention and upvotes that it otherwise wouldn't have gotten.  But more surprisingly, this question never got a single downvote from anyone.  The system then saw an answered question with more than 5 upvotes and 0 downvotes and assumed it was actually a high-quality question useful as an audit.  This time the system was wrong.

> If the question is written in a way that essential information, or information which would make understanding the problem a lot easier (such as what "doesn't work" mean, something I see all the time), is missing, I downvote and comment about it. Is this wrong?

You are free to vote however you wish as long as you aren't serial voting or committing actual voting fraud.  That being said, your criteria for downvoting questions with vague descriptions of "it doesn't work" is reasonable and mainstream.  Don't let this series of unfortunate events overly influence your voting habits.

Comment: "You are free to vote however you wish as long as you aren't serial voting or committing actual voting fraud." Then why does the audit system care if you downvote a high quality question?

Comment: The question also seems to be missing an explanation of exactly what the error is and how the output differs from the desired result. In other words, close-worthy. At any rate, it won't be appearing as an audit anymore.

Comment: @BenAaronson The idea of the First Post queue is to give helpful feedback to new users.  So to this end, voting in ways similar to what they can expect from the rest of the community is helpful.  In this case, the audit got a non-representative view from the community because of the bounty.