# Reopen Votes Audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Please take a look at this question: [Nginx to host app in different location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046159/nginx-to-host-app-in-different-location)

That's clearly about configuring Nginx isn't it? So apparently others thought so and apparently it was closed. Since Nginx configuration should rightfully belong on ServerFault.

But this came up in my reopen votes review queue and I voted that it should remain closed. But the moment I did so that huge banner popped up saying I had flunked an audit. How come?

Update Oct 22: Thanks everyone for your input. I have now flagged the above mentioned post for moderator attention with an explanation. Let's see how it goes.

Update Oct 24: Thanks to your close votes on it, the question 'in question' has been put on hold. Yet the moderator attention flag I made is still in a pending state.

Comment: Was that question closed? It looks like the question was probably boosted into the "this is a really good question" threshold the algorithm looks at by the bounty that was set on it.

Comment: @TZHX nope - never had a single close vote on it. Positively scored question, 2 positively scored answers, one zero score accepted and an automatic awarded bounty. It's just a *really* unfortunate audit to have been picked given the audit reason and the content of the post.

Comment: @JonC Thanks for the confirmation. It seems strange that a question that was never actually judged in this manner should be used as an audit, but I can't think of a better way of doing it. I'm sure there's a Feature-request somewhere about disallowing questions that have had bounties as audits somewhere but can't find it.

Comment: Actually... There's a [comment here by Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560) that suggests they're already excluded (or should be). Weird.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Hope someday there will be a process to audit upvotes on dodgy questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a rubbish audit there, and you should flag it for moderator attention. It also appears the post has already been put on hold for off topic, which is exactly the right course of action here, in my opinion.

Comment: Now it might come up on the reopen queue once again :)