# Dispute a Low Quality Review post

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I came across [this answer here during the LQP review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14830444)

I felt it was a request for clarification from the author. So I chose a deletion of the post. However I failed as it was an answer and accepted by the author. I can understand that it may have led the user to answer their question, but doesn't consist of an actual answer (At least not one that should be used in the quality check for the review queue). Am I correct in my belief or have I been a bad boy today?

Comment: It appears you were thrown off by the presence of question marks. If the sentences were rephrased as statements, rather than questions, would that make it seem more like an answer to you?

Comment: IMHO that answer answers the question, even if it's just an array of rhetorical questions.

Comment: Having rhetorical questions in the review queue seems like a bad example to be testing people with, it can be very confusing for users as trying to get that language across without expressions can make life difficult. However I'Ve taken the advice onboard and will keep an eye out for future cases like this.

Comment: You're right that it's not a very good *audit*. I will agree with you there. Unfortunately, the audits are picked automatically based on heuristics, rather than being manually chosen. Some less-than-stellar audits sneak through. Good news is, I doubt you can be review banned by failing one audit.

Comment: I'm aware, I'm also aware the mods can manually remove bad audits from the list. If other people agree, then a request can be made. I wanted to make sure that it should be removed from the audit checks before I request it.

Comment: @Draken Mods have no special powers to determine audits, any more than any other user on the site does.

Comment: @Draken Users are going to come across real actual posts that have rhetorical questions as answers.  If they don't learn that such posts are actually answers, and shouldn't be deleted, because you refuse to allow them to be audits, then users like you won't learn that suggesting deletion on posts like this is wrong, and that they shouldn't do it.  Clearly this audit was highly successful in determining that you weren't reviewing properly, and teaching you how to properly review posts like this.  Why in the world do you want to deprive others of that?

Comment: @Servy So comments that lead people to answers that are then copy and pasted as answers to get reputation are good answers now? These were originally comments posted to point the OP in the right direction and although provide the route to get to the answer, don't actually provide the answer. This is why I consider it a bad audit check

Comment: @Draken If you think the post isn't a *good* answer you're free to vote accordingly.  It clearly is *an* answer, as it successfully answered the question for the author.  You don't delete answers for being bad answers.  The problems with this answer are trivially edited, as you simply have a problem with its grammar, but even if you couldn't (or didn't want to) that doesn't change the fact that deletion is not the course of action for an answer that you think isn't a good answer.

Comment: Cody Gray has now updated it into a better answer, consider this case closed and lesson learned. I'll keep an eye out for them in future

Comment: Also answer has 10 votes and +50 bounty on it... It is hard to argue that it is very bad answer even in original state - it is good idea to go to actual post from reviews to see post with full context if you are not 100% sure how to vote (and skip is always ok).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The votes can easily be inflated due to the bounty. They even banned bounty questions from appearing in several audit question queues. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227647_300560). Not sure if LQP is included

Answer (score 3):

Don't you think that an answer that answers the question, even if phrased grammatically as a question, should be an answer?  Does it really look like that post is actually seeking information from the author, or is is simply posing rhetorical questions that will lead the reader to the solution?  Did you try editing the grammar of the post from a question to a statement, if you feel that the phrasing detracts from the answer's quality, or at least commenting to the author that phrasing the answer as a statement, rather than a question, might be preferable?

Comment: In actual fact, the "answer" was a comment originally that the user copy and pasted to be an answer on the OP's behalf. So, again, I feel this is a bad test for the LQP queue

Comment: @Draken So they in fact knew that the information was a suitable answer to the question for the question author before posting it.  Sure sounds like they weren't actually requesting information from the author, and were instead providing an answer to the question.

Comment: Look at the comments from the question and it might make more sense.

Comment: @Draken the comment and the answer that copied it were from the same user.

Comment: Also, +1 for irony.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I'm aware of that, hence it looking more like a request for clarification than an answer