# I refuse to click "I Understand"

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed a LQP audit on this https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8384194.

I flagged it as a link-only answer, but apparently because the answer was deemed useful and got 5 upvotes/25 bonus points makes it not a link-only answer. In that case, why are we being ambushed and not shown that information at the time of review?

Ordinarily, I wouldn't put a rant on meta, but this is adding insult to injury as last week I was review-banned for marking an answer as OK when the system said it was a link-only answer. That answer actually did answer the question but happened to add a link for extra info.

Anyone care to point out where I'm going wrong?

I now have a 7-day review ban thanks to this issue, but the irony is that the answer used for the audit has now actually been deleted!

Oh well, I guess while I'm in exile I can at least bask in the glow of my own righteousness.

Comment: lucky it does not come to my review queue.I would fail too :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET worth noting that bounty (+25) was _auto_ awarded; asker wasn't involved

Comment: [Timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30243286/timeline), for reference.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275272 "bad audits are like plane crashes"

Comment: Can't you fix the audit for the future by taking the OPPOSITE action? (obviously won't fix your problem). But IIRC, this answer is an audit because NO ONE DVed it. So if you DV it, you will make sure it won't appear in future audits. Again, nothing good for you right now...

Comment: That post is definitely VLQ. I've dv'ed, in the hopes that eventually it'll go negative and we can get rid of it.

Comment: _Looks like a rotten apple on a sign to me._ Am I seriously the only person who doesn't know what this means? Also: _not a pony-farm_ - I mean, I can tell from context what it means but if feels like I'm missing a key reference.

Comment: @BSMP Googling "rotten apple on a sign" yields 1 result, the above comment from BradleyDotNET. So it' either a very colloquial saying of his, or a typo. Either way, I'm interpreting it as an indication of support. :) Pony-farm (I believe) is meant to indicate a wonderful place where everything (and everyone) is fantastic and you have a wonderful time. As πάντα ῥεῖ says, this is (normally) not your usual SO experience.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET was referencing (if I'm correct) ["Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: @Deduplicator bad audits may be like plane crashes - to the people involved they are serious. First the system throws some junk at the reviewer, then when the reviewer answers correctly, they get hit with "you're wrong - click I Understand". Bring on the "I don't understand" button, I say.

Comment: @royhowie Yep, that is what I was referencing :) (note the included pictures)

Comment: @DeanOC my comment was cleansed (and the responses to it purged), but I wasn't actually calling you uncultured—I was not trying to insult you in any way. I'm sorry the sarcasm in the comment wasn't apparent enough.

Comment: @royhowie Actually my bad. You didn't insult me at all, and I was being sarcastic myself (why won't they invent an internet where sarcasm is not misconstrued??). Sorry for making you think I was being serious. Thanks for the link to the apples post; I learnt something new.

Comment: This is a perfect example of [Poe's Law](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law).

Comment: I object to being asked to click a button bearing a statement with which I disagree. Whether I genuinely don't understand, or do understand but disagree, I'm not clicking that button. It's the reason why I don't bother with the review queue anymore.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300713/i-know-this-is-an-audit-and-it-is-bad-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bad audits happen to everyone.  They are a consequence of the automated method in which audits are selected (mostly due to bad upvotes).

If you are unsure of whether an audit is good or bad, feel free to post on meta and ask for feedback.  You may learn something.  You may be surprised to see how many times there is a "bad" audit that was actually good.  Worst case is you'll be told that the audit was truly crap and you lost nothing except for <s>meta rep</s> nothing.

But if you are certain it is a bad audit, then just chalk it up to bad luck.  Some real crap gets stupid upvotes all the time, and as a consequence they can be selected as audits.  If you find a crap post as an audit, then just go to the actual post and do the opposite that the audit wanted (upvote a "known bad post" or downvote/vote-to-close a "known good post").  That will help ensure no one else is trapped by the same post by disqualifying it as an audit.

Fortunately, 1 failed audit is not going to impact you significantly.  You can't get banned from reviewing from a single bad audit and fortunately there not that many bad audits so you should not see serious punishment from bad audits.  If you are extremely unlucky and get a number of bad audits, you can try contacting the SE community team for a reprieve (see the ["contact us"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link in the footer).  It would help your case with specific examples so be sure to mention the bad audits in your message.

You may also be interested in [Review audits and "I understand" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button) on MSE.

Comment: Thanks. From others' responses, it seems to me that it was more of a case that I was unlucky to cop a dodgy audit rather than there being a fundamental problem with my definition of a link-only answer. So I'll just move on. :)

Comment: @DeanOC the simplest test I know for detecting a **worthless** link-only answer is to ignore the links.  If you understand that there is an answer (maybe a bad one, but still a valid answer) without the links, then it is not link only.  If there is no answer, just a bunch of words that say "go here", then it is link only.

Comment: Do we need audits for audits...?

Comment: @deceze despite the complaints on meta, I don't think the audits are really as bad as it seems since no one every opens a post to say what a good audit a question was.  But the MSE proposal I linked is probably the best solution to the problem (specifically Brad's answer),

Comment: @deceze Yes, desperately. I volunteer.

Comment: @psubsee2003: There's a certain amount of resignation that sets in; I've reported maybe two or three bad audits, but the results from those reports have not been sufficiently positive to encourage me to report the other three or four dozen I've run into. (I've toyed with the idea of simply biting the bullet and reporting every single audit I disagree with, but that seems too much like "Don't disrupt Wikipedia to prove a point" for my liking.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy then let's support Brad's idea - I'll go throw a bounty on it now

Comment: Two things that are wrong: If you were banned from review in the last 30 days, you can get banned again just for a single fail. Also, you don't need to contact SE to have a review ban lifted; moderators can lift the ban after a meta question, and it's better to post on meta about a bad review audit so other users can make it even less likely to show up as an audit again.

Comment: @gparyani I never said that you won't get banned for a single fail after getting banned.  I said "you can't get banned for failing a single audit" which is still true.  Once you have been banned, if you fail again, you are getting judged on both the new failure and your past history of failure.

Comment: @gparyani also, yes, moderators can unban you, but there is no direct means of communicating with moderators short of a meta post or finding one in chat.  With the employee route, you have a direct means of communication, which makes it easier to state your case.

Comment: "You can't get banned for failing a single audit" implies that there is no case under which one can get banned for a single fail. This is not the case; if one has gotten banned in the last 30 days, then that is one case where one can get banned for a single fail.