# I know this is an audit and it is bad. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I was going through the low quality post review queue and got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9030551).  I am 99.99% certain that it is an audit as it is a question and the LQ queue no longer does questions.  I right clicked on the question title and opened the question in a new tab to confirm my suspicions and sure enough [Inject javascript gecko fennec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510609/inject-javascript-gecko-fennec) has 5 upvotes.  My problem is that in my opinion this is a low quality post but if it is an audit I will fail if I vote to close.

What should I do in situations like this?  Should I:

- Pass the audit and get on with my life?
- Pass the audit and then bring it to meta to have it question removed from the audit pool?
- Skip it and give it a down vote/close vote.  possibly submit to the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room / create meta post?

Right now I have done nothing with the review.

Comment: Yeah, it's an audit case because of the votes. It's yet another instance where a question received a large number of upvotes [entirely due to it having a bounty at one point](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes). Sounds like the Low Quality Posts queue doesn't currently exclude those from audits: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560 but other queues do.

Comment: What is an audit?

Comment: I think you already did the right thing by raising it on meta to highlight it is a bad audit. Note how the meta-effect has taken over and fixed it. Good one.

Comment: @lolesque [see this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @lolesque an audit is a review that has a "know" outcome.  If you review it correctly you pass otherwise you fail.  Too many failed audits will lead to a review ban

Comment: What do you mean you "right clicked the question title"? (thank you for the fix. I thought that was the case)

Comment: @CayceK The question title is a link to the querstion.  I right clicked on it an opened it in a new tab.  I have edit the question.

Comment: I failed an audit today. I think it was first posts (question). I tried commenting to say the question body was very long, then it failed me. Otherwise, the question was good... Does anything happen if we fail audits?

Comment: @HunterStevens If you fail to many you could get review banned.

Comment: @NathanOliver - how do Inject JavaScript into Fennec? Why do you think this question is bad? It's readily answerable, though the English is not so good.

Comment: @superluminary I consider the question as to broad and I would and did vote for it to be that.  The question is very general and so it could get lots of different answers.

Comment: @superluminary I am not an expert so I don't know.  I voted how I felt and the community seams to agree.  If you fell it should be open you could always cast a reopen vote.  As of right now I see no one has.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you. I have only failed 2 since I earned the privilege (a couple of weeks). I think the first was a mistake, and the second was just a comment. Not even a down vote.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

That depends on your alignment:

- If you are lawful good, pass the audit, then go to the question and vote-to-close.
- If you are neutral good, pass the audit and get on with your life.
- If you are chaotic good, skip/fail the audit, then go to the question and vote-to-close.

I won't cover neutral or evil options because only good people ask questions on Meta, right?

Comment: total +1 for D&D reference.

Comment: I like this term `Chaotic good` +1

Comment: @Moudiz Of course, the term is [not my own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_%28Dungeons_%26_Dragons%29).

Comment: @TylerH not familar with this game but it sounds good

Comment: Surely passing the audit by knowingly providing the desired answer - instead of the honest one - would be chaotic? And lawful would be following the rules even though you know you'll fail?

Comment: @AntP Following the rules, even when you disagree with them personally, is lawful behavior. This is actually one of the most common paradoxes that lawful characters often face; what to do when their personal or sworn code/belief system conflicts with the law.

Comment: But following the rules of an audit means giving an honest answer, not fudging it to make sure you give the answer that will pass when you know it's not the right one (i.e. cheating).

Comment: @AntP If the audit system were perfect, yes, but the system is inherently flawed (as this question illustrates). An unflawed system would not erroneously mark bad questions as good questions and then disguise those "good" questions as bad ones for the purposes of an audit. Failing the audit on principle could prevent you from helping others in the future by suspending your ability to audit. A chaotic good person values personal freedom over systems and rigors; they would never do what was expected (marking this audit as "Looks OK") if they felt it were wrong.

Comment: @AntP The audit system is not an honesty test. There's no way to cheat by pressing the wrong answer. It is designed to make sure you are paying attention, not making the right choices.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from but I very much disagree - the audit system is supposed to be a transparent part of the review system and its intended use is for you to apply your knowledge of the rules and conventions of the site as you would any other review item. Using your intuition to detect an audit and deduce the desired answer is intentionally undermining the system albeit with good intentions. I guess it's a matter of perspective.

Comment: @AntP The whole point of the audit system is to prevent robo-reviewing. There's nothing wrong with opening every single question you review in a new tab to check whether it's an audit or not; the SO team would actually probably *prefer* that, because it means you're providing each answer with extra individual attention. Even if you are only doing it to avoid failing audits (e.g. the "wrong" reasons), it's still inadvertently a good practice.

Comment: I never said there was anything *wrong* with it but that's a workaround to a flaw in the system (known bad audits), it's not the intended use case.

Comment: @AntP Sorry; I assumed that when you said "(i.e. cheating)" you were implying it was wrong.

Comment: Cheating was maybe not the best word.

Comment: @AntP Either way, thanks for the discussion :-) Always good to keep people honest!

Comment: @AntP FWIW ["I typically open the items in queue in separate tab (for more thorough review)..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Answer (score 22):

Skip the audit, downvote it, and move on.

From [Shog's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/148949):

> Right now, these audit questions are selected using the following criteria:
>
> - Recently asked
> - Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
> - Never locked, migrated, or deleted
> - No close votes or downvotes, ever (only for close/reopen audits)
> - (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

In this case, receiving a downvote would remove it, since it's previous score was 5, and the downvote would knock it out below the score threshhold.

Also, in the Close Review and Reopen review, a downvote or close vote is also sufficient.

Comment: Is there a reason you would skip the audit instead of passing it?

Comment: I don't waste my time on bad audits; it's one more vote I could use for a legitimate review

Comment: Ah okay.  I forget that audits count as a review item.