# I think this is a terrible "audit" question

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I [failed an audit in the reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11244391) on the question "[Does the C++ standard support processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300580/does-the-c-standard-support-processes)".

I got scolded for saying it should stay closed.

My reasoning:

- It contains three questions.
- Two of the three questions are opinion-based.

  - *is there any discussion on whether such a feature should be added?*
  - *I'm just curious if C++ supports this directly or will in the future.*
- The third is a duplicate.

  - *is there a way to execute the bar function in a separate process?*

Am I way off base there?

### EDIT

The top/accepted answer here [I refuse to click "I Understand"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296506/i-refuse-to-click-i-understand/296511#296511) says "*If you are unsure of whether an audit is good or bad, feel free to post on meta and ask for feedback.*"  So, IMO, unless you are asking about an audit question somebody else asked about, it's not a dup.

The question isn't "*why are there bad audit questions?*".

The question is "*am I off-base thinking THIS is a bad audit question?*"

Comment: I think it is fine and It was even used as a dupe target the day after it was asked as another user was asking the same thing.  I look at as a single two part question instead of two separate questions.

Comment: Yeah, this is *not* a duplicate. Hopefully the retag will make it more clear.

Comment: I don't get the point.  Just edit the question to remove the subjective parts, they are not critical to the question.  So the next guy won't have to disagree with 11 SO users that gave it a Nice Question badge and fail the audit.  They might well disagree with the edit, don't get into a rollback war.

Comment: The other thing I have yet to find here on SO is how concerned should I be with the occasional "failed audit"?   I am going to get the dunce cap the next round of silly hats, or does it actually matter in some material way?

Comment: If its once and a while don't worry about it.  No one can be perfect.  If you get suspended then you may need to reevaluate how you are reviewing.

Comment: wrt failed audits, take a look at questions in [meta-tag:review-suspension] tag

Comment: Interesting to see myself participating in audited questions now :-) ...

Comment: @gnat Thank you, that was very helpful.

Comment: @JohnHascall Well, at least it was easy to just answer that question(s). And the question itself was upvoted several times after giving that answer. So it looks a number of users think that Q&A pair is useful for future research.

Answer (score 7):

> Two of the three questions are opinion-based.

"is there any discussion on whether such a feature should be added?" is not opinion-based. Asking whether the relevant committees are discussing a particular to extension to C++ is not asking for an opinion, it's asking for facts. What would be asking for an opinion is asking for the committees' likely conclusion before there is a conclusion, but the question isn't doing that.

And the other supposedly opinion-based question, "I'm just curious if C++ supports this directly or will in the future.", is not a question at all and doesn't implicitly ask anything the rest of the question doesn't already explicitly ask.

> The third is a duplicate.

While it's impossible to rule this out, neither your question nor any comments on the question you ask about provide a link to what it's supposedly a duplicate of.

Comment: "...will in the future" is suspiciously open-ended. Who knows what C++45 will support? A more sensible scoping -- "will in the near future", maybe -- would be a lot easier to deal with. Of course, that's only an edit away.