# Possible bad audit review in First Post

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Came across this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13646114

To me it seemed a bit poor as they hadn't posted any code to the stackoverflow website and just relied on an external link (That could stop working in the future). Though AngularJS is not my forté, I thought this was a bad example for an audit review. Was I incorrect?

[Edit]
I've flagged it as off-topic, see what the community concludes on if they wish to close it. If they don't, could an admin remove it from the review audit stack?

[Edit 2]
The question has been put on hold, that should remove it from the audit review stack.

Comment: I am seriously not understanding why you asked this , you can just press skip button, other user will handle that.

Comment: You don't know angular and reviewing angular post?  Sorry but You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Audit reviews are supposed to help train you into becoming a better auditor and some of them can be suspect. You just need to look at the tag for [disputed-review-aduits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits?sort=votes&pageSize=15). Generally a good question should include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not rely on an external link that could die. This is why I believe it's a bad audit review, the question isn't necessarily going to hold up to the *test of time*. This doesn't promote good auditing practices, but would love confirmation

Comment: [Also, please refer to this answer for why I was posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296511/833070)

Comment: related: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601) and [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: This is a case where the voting on a question was severely distorted by the fact that it had had a bounty placed on it. Bounties are notorious for directing tons of upvotes at borderline questions, and previously-bountied questions [should be ineligible as audit cases](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227647_300560). Not sure why this one was still being used as an audit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions having a link of an external site that wants to solve /debug a problem should be closed rather than deleted.

IMO it's a bad example for an audit review.

Comment: Closing without edition is ubiquitous to deletion. So, suggesting that a question should be rightfully closed but not deleted is contradicting.