# Why is this a valid SO question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

[Where do I file bugs for JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30826796) is about where to report a bug. I don't understand why this is valid for SO.

I got it as an [audit question on triage, and I failed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8682344). Yes it is a question clear and that can be answered, but that solely is not enough to make it good.

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: You failed your audit because the question is known to be good ... that is, the community evaluated it as such. That being said, I agree with you and would have failed as well.

Comment: @Bart - So the system picks randomly "good question" from the site for the audits? Somehow I always thought maybe moderators selected good questions for audit, or something like that.

Comment: Because broken audits slip into the system.

Comment: @Dzyann don't quote me on this, but I think what becomes audits are posts that are NON-controversial (so posts with only upvotes, no downvotes, are seen as good, etc). So when ppl don't downvote properly (or upvote crap) yes, audits slip. The best way to stop that would be to go on the original question and downvote it, to break the "this question is good, without disagreement" point of view from the automated system

Comment: @Patrice - That's interesting, so there is a lot of value on flagging old questions as well, then, because there many that are not good fit for current SO rules and could lead to bad audits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply said, it's a standard GIGO situation:

*Garbage in*: Those who saw that question did not close it as off-topic, up-voting instead, even though it's a clear product support / offsite-resource request.

results in

*Garbage out*: The automatic review selection process selecting it due to the unambiguous signal that it's a good question.

There are good reasons the audit-selection is automated:

1. Anything else *doesn't scale*.
2. Even more drama because there's some specific idiot who screwed up your day.
3. [Despite appearances](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275272), it works well.

And if there's a dud, at least we can take the proper action *now*.

Comment: Oh well, that's good to know. I just wanted to make sure I understand things correctly, as it is some questions are unclear whether we should close or not, but this seemed so clear.

Comment: Quick question, what is the reason for "possible" spam message at the top? It doesn't look like spam to me. Is it just for tricking you?

Comment: Well, either the system genuinely evaluated it as "possible spam, proceed with even more caution than normal". Or it randomly decided that this known-good audit should be used to test whether you trust the automatics too much. Both things happen by design.

Comment: Well, I take the good from the bad. At least I have cleared out some misconceptions I had about the audits. And there is nothing else to be done, right? Is there a queue for "invalid audit" questions? Or just posting here is good enough?

Comment: Just take a good hard look at the audit, and if you were wrong, move on. If you aren't sure, ask on [chat] or meta. If you are sure you were right, just take it out of circulation by counter-action. If it also got you review-banned, politely ask on meta and mention that so a mod can take care of it, or the community of your misperception.