# Yet another bad audit (and a ban this time!)

Tags: feature-request

The accepted answer to [Android welcome screen - multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474226/android-welcome-screen-multiple-images) is:

[image]

From the same thread this was selected as an audit:

[image]

The accepted answer links are external, for the audit review answer **internal**. The text of both answers is substantially the same, and though the audit review answer was posted later it was within the 5 minute grace period for the first.

### Please cease to select audits on a purely mechanical basis and have some human review their suitability independently from user votes.

Comment: I'd suggest making the feature request more noticeable within your question. **Please cease to select audits on a purely mechanical basis and have some human review their suitability independently from user votes.**

Comment: as a feature request, this would be a dupe of [Manual audit validation to create highly-reusable unambiguous audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284412/839601) and [Do something about failed audit questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275188/839601). I picked another dupe because it explains why audit post you failed would stay even with manual selection of audits

Comment: Holy [excrement], I thought my tags reveiced quite some bad answers. Six link-only answers in two hours?

Answer (score 5):

The existence of a second non-answer to the question that hasn't been deleted as NAA (yet) in no way invalidates your audit, or makes that non-answer an answer.

Comment: @pnuts You're asserting that the audit is wrong purely because there is another answer that's not deleted that's exactly the same.  I'm saying that that's a fallacy.  The fact that a different answer wasn't deleted doesn't mean that both answers must be perfectly fine.  It just means that the other answer wasn't moderated.  It being inconsistent doesn't mean that both must be fine, or that there's a problem with the audit.  You, as an auditor, should have *flagged the other answer* when you noticed the inconsistency.

Comment: @pnuts You stated that the audit is wrong because there's another answer that isn't deleted.  I'm saying that's a fallacy.  You have provided no other reasoning for why the audit is wrong besides that.  If you feel that the answer is actually an answer, then *explain why you feel that is* when evaluated in isolation, and when no considering the other answers to that question.

Comment: So why is the audit wrong then? This looks like NAA to me, we've always had link only answers as bad...

Comment: @pnuts I supposed *technically* all you said is, "I failed this audit but there is this other answer that's virtually identical and that isn't deleted".  You implied that the audit is wrong because of that reason.  If you don't feel that way then all of that information is simply irrelevant, and you have provided *no* explanation (either correct or incorrect) for why the audit is wrong at all.

Comment: @pnuts First off, if you feel that that's why it's an answer then *say that in your question* rather than spending your entire question saying that it's exactly the same as another non-deleted answer.  Second, it's *not* appropriate to just post a link to a duplicate post as an answer.  You should be voting/flagging for closure in such a case.  it *is* appropriate to delete an answer that is really just a duplicate flag in disguise.

Comment: Definitely a low quality post, i would have downvoted/deleted. It's not NAA, but that's not what this queue is reviewing.

Comment: i assume the low quality queue, guess i should ask. :)

Comment: @pnuts The fact that someone posted an answer to say that a post is a duplicate instead of voting/flagging for closure in no way means that the post isn't a duplicate.  It just means that people didn't use the appropriate site feature to indicate that the post was a duplicate.

Comment: @pnuts An answer that just links to another SO post, and provides no other meaningful information, is essentially asserting that the post is a duplicate, as they're saying that the other question provides all of the information needed to answer this question.

Comment: @pnuts If this is a late answer then in order to fail this audit you'd not only need to not vote to delete it, but you would need to assert that this post shouldn't be downvoted, doesn't need any editing, doesn't need any comments, and doesn't merit flagging *for any reason*.  That's *clearly* not the case here.  At a bare minimum this is a low quality post that should be downvoted and commented on to explain why it is not up to the site's standards.  That you felt that literally nothing should be done here unquestionably merits a failed auidit.

Comment: @pnuts The one word "ViewPager" doesn't seem anywhere close to qualifying as an answer.

Comment: I could see "use ViewPager" as a qualifying answer, albeit a very poor one worthy of *at least* a downvote, which would have resulted in passing the audit, no? it having a downvote already shouldn't deter from adding another..

Comment: @pnuts So you felt that the existing comment of, "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." what an appropriate comment for that answer?  I thought your whole premise here is that that comment is wrong?  Now you're asserting that it's completely valid?

Comment: @pnuts Where do you get that from?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @pnuts You do realize that that's the auto-comment generated for the link only answer deletion option in the LQP queue, no?  So stating that that's an accurate comment means that you feel the post should be flagged to go into that queue, and that it should be deleted.

Comment: @pnuts I acknowledged that I have no idea what you mean by two specific comments of yours (which you still haven't actually explained in any way).  That's not saying that I don't understand anything about the question.  Stating that my conclusion doesn't follow doesn't mean that it doesn't follow.  You need to follow up such an assertion with an explanation of *why* it doesn't follow for it to mean anything.  Just saying, "you're wrong" is a meaningless statement, when unsupported.

Comment: @pnuts Wow, you managed to flag this post as NAA and have it declined an entire week before it was first posted.  How did you manage to do *that*?  I don't think that it's much of a leap to say that the auto-comment that's explaining why a post has been deleted, if accurate, describes why the post should be deleted.  For that to be false would mean that you feel it's inappropriate for it to be the comment posted when deleting a post from the LQP queue.  That's an assertion you'll need to support.

Comment: @pnuts No, you're just saying that because one flag to some post you didn't even mention was declined, that means that you should never use that flag on any post, ever.  And you're accusing me of statements that don't follow...  I can't possibly comment on why your other flag was declined, not knowing the post flagged.  I can say that it's incorrect to assume that you should never flag any post for that reason just because it was declined.